# ld creates elf segments with wrong permissions

Tags: linker, ld, elf

I'm writing a bare-metal aarch64 program (toolchain aarch64-unknown-elf-) which I'm building using the following linker script:

```
SECTIONS {
    .text :  {
        *(.text*)
    }

    .rodata ALIGN(CONSTANT(COMMONPAGESIZE)) :  {
        *(.rodata*)
    }

    .data ALIGN(CONSTANT(COMMONPAGESIZE)) : {
        *(.data .data.*)
    }

    .bss (NOLOAD) :  {  
        __bss_start = .;
        *(.bss*) 
        *(COMMON)   
        __bss_end = .;
    }
}
```

Using readelf to analyze the final executable I get the following sections and segments (i.e. program headers):

```
There are 19 section headers, starting at offset 0xa4f58:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            0000000000000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        0000000000000000 010000 00f600 00  AX  0   0 2048
  [ 2] .rodata           PROGBITS        0000000000010000 020000 0079f9 00   A  0   0 4096
  [ 3] .data             PROGBITS        0000000000018000 028000 001160 00  WA  0   0  8
  [ 4] .bss              NOBITS          0000000000019160 029160 002320 00  WA  0   0  8
  [ 5] .debug_info       PROGBITS        0000000000000000 029160 02d080 00      0   0  1
  [ 6] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        0000000000000000 0561e0 009f28 00      0   0  1
  [ 7] .debug_loclists   PROGBITS        0000000000000000 060108 016841 00      0   0  1
  [ 8] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS        0000000000000000 076950 0013c0 00      0   0 16
  [ 9] .debug_macro      PROGBITS        0000000000000000 077d10 003b67 00      0   0  1
  [10] .debug_line       PROGBITS        0000000000000000 07b877 00f6be 00      0   0  1
  [11] .debug_str        PROGBITS        0000000000000000 08af35 00eaeb 01  MS  0   0  1
  [12] .debug_line_str   PROGBITS        0000000000000000 099a20 0027db 01  MS  0   0  1
  [13] .comment          PROGBITS        0000000000000000 09c1fb 000057 01  MS  0   0  1
  [14] .debug_frame      PROGBITS        0000000000000000 09c258 002a40 00      0   0  8
  [15] .debug_rnglists   PROGBITS        0000000000000000 09ec98 0016a0 00      0   0  1
  [16] .symtab           SYMTAB          0000000000000000 0a0338 003a80 18     17 372  8
  [17] .strtab           STRTAB          0000000000000000 0a3db8 0010d5 00      0   0  1
  [18] .shstrtab         STRTAB          0000000000000000 0a4e8d 0000c7 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  D (mbind), p (processor specific)

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x0
There is 1 program header, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x010000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x019160 0x01b480 RWE 0x10000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .text .rodata .data .bss
```

My issue here is that the linker is merging sections with different permissions in a single segment with all permissions, even when I'm guaranteeing that the data sections are in a separate pages (by aligning them accordingly).

I experimented with different sizes for the alignment of the data section using hugepages (of 2MiB). Here I already get three segments with the correct permissions:

```
There are 19 section headers, starting at offset 0xacf58:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            0000000000000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        0000000000000000 010000 00f600 00  AX  0   0 2048
  [ 2] .rodata           PROGBITS        0000000000200000 020000 0079f9 00   A  0   0 4096
  [ 3] .data             PROGBITS        0000000000400000 030000 001160 00  WA  0   0  8
  [ 4] .bss              NOBITS          0000000000401160 031160 002320 00  WA  0   0  8
  [ 5] .debug_info       PROGBITS        0000000000000000 031160 02d080 00      0   0  1
  [ 6] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        0000000000000000 05e1e0 009f28 00      0   0  1
  [ 7] .debug_loclists   PROGBITS        0000000000000000 068108 016841 00      0   0  1
  [ 8] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS        0000000000000000 07e950 0013c0 00      0   0 16
  [ 9] .debug_macro      PROGBITS        0000000000000000 07fd10 003b67 00      0   0  1
  [10] .debug_line       PROGBITS        0000000000000000 083877 00f6be 00      0   0  1
  [11] .debug_str        PROGBITS        0000000000000000 092f35 00eaeb 01  MS  0   0  1
  [12] .debug_line_str   PROGBITS        0000000000000000 0a1a20 0027db 01  MS  0   0  1
  [13] .comment          PROGBITS        0000000000000000 0a41fb 000057 01  MS  0   0  1
  [14] .debug_frame      PROGBITS        0000000000000000 0a4258 002a40 00      0   0  8
  [15] .debug_rnglists   PROGBITS        0000000000000000 0a6c98 0016a0 00      0   0  1
  [16] .symtab           SYMTAB          0000000000000000 0a8338 003a80 18     17 372  8
  [17] .strtab           STRTAB          0000000000000000 0abdb8 0010d5 00      0   0  1
  [18] .shstrtab         STRTAB          0000000000000000 0ace8d 0000c7 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  D (mbind), p (processor specific)

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x0
There are 3 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x010000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x00f600 0x00f600 R E 0x10000
  LOAD           0x020000 0x0000000000200000 0x0000000000200000 0x0079f9 0x0079f9 R   0x10000
  LOAD           0x030000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x001160 0x003480 RW  0x10000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .text 
   01     .rodata 
   02     .data .bss
```

My main question would be what are the rules or heuristics for ld to decide when to create a different section? My thinking was granularity of protection (i.e. page size) and permissions, but maybe I'm wrong. I've tried to dig a bit through the code, but it goes a bit over my head. Don't loaders use the segment information to load and set permissions? If so, this could result in setting the wrong permissions (in page tables or whatever).

Comment: It is an interesting question, but it occurrs to me, if this is a bare-metal program, then are you even using those flags?

Comment: I'm still using this info to construct page-tables and set up other protection mechanisms.